# Remix IDE Desktop + Geth node as test network

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, json-rpc, ipc

I'm trying to connect the Remix Desktop client to my local Geth node. as usual i added:

> geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain https://remix.ethereum.org

while starting up the node. This obviously only works connecting to the Webapp version of Remix.
Is there another way i can connect the Remix desktop client directly to my own node as Metamask also only works in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

```
--rpccorsdomain "package://a7df6d3c223593f3550b35e90d7b0b1f.mod"
```

Does the trick!